# Unable to instantiate receiver no empty constructor

Tags: java, android

I want to perform operation when the user has internet activated but i get the following error :

java.lang.InstantiationException: can't instantiate class com.project.proj.NetworkChangeReceiver; no empty constructor

In an activity class i have written the following

```
NetworkChangeReceiver net = new NetworkChangeReceiver(getBaseContext());
```

where am I going wrong. Please help !

```
public class NetworkChangeReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
 {
    Context mContext;
    public NetworkChangeReceiver(Context context)
    {
        mContext= context;
     }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(final Context context, final Intent intent) {

        String status = NetworkUtil.getConnectivityStatusString(context);
if (status == "Wifi enabled")
{
    Database details=new Database(mContext);
    details.open();
    List<String> detailsId;
    detailsId=details.getRecords();
    retrieveValuesFromListMethod1(detailsId);
    Toast.makeText(context, "working properly", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
        Toast.makeText(context, status, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }


public void retrieveValuesFromListMethod1(List detailsId)
{

    Iterator itr = detailsId.iterator();
    while(itr.hasNext())
    {
    //do something

    }
}
}
```

Comment: You need a constructor without parameters.

Comment: Just add a constructor w/o parameters no?

Comment: @niekbut then i get Nullpointer exception unable to start reciever !

Comment: @marco Database details=new Database(mContext); I need to pass a context for the database to open ! what do i pass then in place of mcontext?

Comment: You have the context in onReceive (first param, context)

Comment: well, I'm such a noob,  Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove:

```
Context mContext;
public NetworkChangeReceiver(Context context)
{
    mContext= context;
 }
```

Comment: but then i get Nullpointer exception unable to start reciever !

Comment: @user3496326 you don't know how to properly use a BroadcastReceiver. See Boban's response to understand.

Comment: @shkschneider I deleted it but how do i pass a context to Database details=new Database(mContext); to make it work ?

Comment: @user3496326 1. read the response 2. adapt your code: use new Database(context) in onReceive(), as told in Boban's response (line 2)

Answer (score 5):

`BroadcastReceiver` can't have other constructor except default. Delete constructor you created.

Also, you don't need to pass context to `BroadcastReceiver`, in `onReceive` parameter is context.