# Notice fragment or activity from broadcast receiver

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, gps, broadcastreceiver

I need notice fragment/activity from broadcast receiver but I cant find solution.

Description: When fragment start my method check if GPS module is ON if no ask user to turn it on. Now I have broadcast receiver for gps and when is gps On or OFF I get message, this works. But now I need do something like interface and when i receive GPS on/off I want call my method in fragment. Im not sure if is clear what I need. Here I try it with interface but then I find so I cant pass interface object to broadcast receiver constructor.

My solution with interface but not working:

```
    public class GpsLocationReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    private INotifyGpsTurnedOn iNotifyGpsTurnedOn = null;

    public GpsLocationReceiver(INotifyGpsTurnedOn iNotifyGpsTurnedOn) {
        this.iNotifyGpsTurnedOn = iNotifyGpsTurnedOn;
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        LocationManager lm = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(Service.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        boolean isEnabled = lm.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        Toast.makeText(context, isEnabled+"",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        if(isEnabled){
            iNotifyGpsTurnedOn.iniGps();
        }
        else{
            iNotifyGpsTurnedOn.askTurnOnGps();
        }
    }

    public interface INotifyGpsTurnedOn {
        public void iniGps();
        public void askTurnOnGps();
    }
}
```

In fragment class I have implement interface with methods, register receiver etc ...

```
 GpsLocationReceiver m_gpsChangeReceiver = new GpsLocationReceiver(this);
    getActivity().registerReceiver(m_gpsChangeReceiver, new IntentFilter(LocationManager.PROVIDERS_CHANGED_ACTION));

    @Override
public void iniGps() {
    mGps.startGps(false);
}

@Override
public void askTurnOnGps() {
    mGps.askUserToTurnOnGPS(getActivity());
}
```

Comment: If your Fragment implements interface `INotifyGpsTurnedOn` I don't see why this won't work. What error are you getting?

Comment: I can not use interface because I can not pass iNotifyGpsTurnedOn in constructor of GpsLocationReceiver, it is not allowed in ext. BroadcastReceiver.

Comment: Of course you can. What error are you getting?

Comment: Exception:Unable to instantiate receiver no empty constructor... I try also add empty constructor or call super but still the same result and then I find this: BroadcastReceiver can't have other constructor except default. Delete constructor you created. Link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23269192/unable-to-instantiate-receiver-no-empty-constructor?rq=1

Comment: When do you get this error?

Comment: Are you declaring this BroadcastReceiver in your manifest? If so, you should remove that. You don't need it there if you are only registering the receiver in code when you want it to be called.

Comment: I just tried this to be sure and it works just fine. As long as you are instantiating the `BroadcastReceiver` yourself and not allowing Android to do it for you (ie: specifying an `intent-filter` in the manifest for the `BroadcastReceiver`, this works just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works just fine. You can declare an `Interface` and provide this in the constuctor. This works as long as you instantiate the `BroadcastReceiver` yourself, and don't let Android do it. You don't need to declare this `BroadcastReceiver` in the manifest.

The reason you are getting `Exception: Unable to instantiate receiver no empty constructor.` is because Android is trying to instantiate the `BroadcastReceiver`. (for whatever reason).

Comment: Thank you David for your help. I can not confirm that your solution is working for me because I already solved it different way but I think your solution will work and I accept your answer. Thx for your time. To the future I will remember your advice.